# Material design not showing angular 12

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, angular12

Material design is not showing up in Angular 12.
Hi, I am new to angular (beginner). I tried using some material design element on top of angular 12, but I cannot see the material design changes in my test application.

Here are steps to reproduce:

1. I created an app "test-anugular-mat" using `ng new test-anugular-mat`.
2. After creating I added angular to the app using `ng add @angular/material`. Here i have disabled "typography styles" and enabled "browser animations".
3. Added imported `MatButton` in `app.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatButton} from '@angular/material/button'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButton
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

4. And added the following in my `index.html`.

```
<h1>testing angular material</h1>
<p>testing angular material!!!</p>
<button mat-fab>test button</button>
<mat-card>Simple card</mat-card>
```

Here is the output I am getting, not the desired angular button or card while using `ng serve`
[image]

So I should get material design, what is the mistake I am doing here ?

Answer (score 2):

You should import `MatButtonModule` instead of `MatButton`.
See correct import syntax https://material.angular.io/components/button/api

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mistaken the "tab" in "<button mat-tab ..." ?

Try with

```
<button mat-button>test button</button>
```

or

```
<button mat-fab>test button</button>
```

EDIT: Are you putting this directly in your "index.html"???
You shoud put your test code in your **"app.component.html"**, not in "index.html"

And for use the material card, you have to import its module as well:
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';

You have all the info components in [HERE](https://v9.material.angular.io/components/card/api)

Comment: I thought I mistyped `fab` as `tab` but same out i am getting. 
Check the card `<mat-card>` result.

Comment: Read the new edit at the end of my answer, I hope it is the wrong thing, and you can solve it.

Comment: The mat card is normal that it doesn't work, because you didn't import its module. You just import MatButton, not MatCardModule